# highcharts column datalabels position gets cut off

Tags: highcharts

I have fiddled here with highcharts.js demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/Venkata/rq0h7o4o/

Data labels goes beyond x-axis. do i need to write formatters or any suggestions?

```
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    "dataLabels": {
                      enabled: true,
                      format: '{point.y:.1f}%',
                      rotation: -90,
                      align: 'right',
                      x: 4,
                      y: 15,
                      crop: false,
                      overflow: 'none'
                  }                        
                }
```

Comment: Reported as bug [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3523). Thanks! As workaround - don't use rotated dataLabels.

Comment: I have fixed it using min height to the bar. Thanks for your help.